# shiro authorization filter getting called multiple times

Tags: java, shiro

I wrote a authentication and authorization module using apache shiro and google oauth and microsoft 365 oauth. It lets users login using there google/ms credential no problem, but the authorization filter gets called so many times. Below is a example of the debug log i get from a single login. So many time the authorization cycle is getting called. So can any one knows how do I address this issue.

```
        17:39:16.998 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.105 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.224 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.348 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.408 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.479 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.596 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.713 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.838 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:17.967 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
        17:39:18.087 [qtp670971910-28] INFO  com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm - GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!
```

---------------------------------------------Edit---------------------------

The shiro ini I have looks as follows,

```
[main]

ssl.enabled = false

authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy

GoogleRealm = com.hap.Google.GoogleRealm
#GoogleRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
googleCredentialsMatcher = com.hap.Google.GoogleCredentialsMatcher
GoogleRealm.credentialsMatcher = $googleCredentialsMatcher

Ms365Realm = com.hap.MsOffice365.Ms365Realm
#Ms365Realm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
Ms365CredentialsMatcher = com.hap.MsOffice365.Ms365CredentialsMatcher
Ms365Realm.credentialsMatcher = $Ms365CredentialsMatcher

securityManager.realms = $GoogleRealm,$Ms365Realm
securityManager.rememberMeManager.cipherKey=kPH+bIxk5D2deZiIxcaaaA==
authc.loginUrl = /views/login-oauth.xhtml



[urls]
#Important
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/views/login-oauth.xhtml = authc
/views/access-denied.xhtml = anon
/logout = logout

/views/* = authc
/css/* = anon
/errors/* = anon
#I have to punch a hole for the css files
#/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

---

The whole code flow is based on the [sample facebook-shiro example](https://mrdwnotes.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-apache-shiro-security-to-allow-login-via-facebook-part-1/)
doGetAuthorizationInfo method inside the googleRealm, which actually fetches the roles and permissions from underlying database(postgres).

```
@Override
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    AuthorizationInfo authorizationInfo = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    try {
        CommonAuthenticationMethods commonAuth = new CommonAuthenticationMethods();
        authorizationInfo = commonAuth.doGetAuthorizationInfo(principals);
        LOGGER.info("GoogleRealm: doGetAuthorizationInfo is called!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug("GoogleRealm : doGetAuthorizationInfo: exception occurred!! " + e.getMessage());
        //throw e;
    }
    return authorizationInfo;
}
```

---

Added the EnvironmentLoaderListener and ShiroFilter like this. following [link](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html)

```
<listener>
            <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

    <filter>
            <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Why is authorization filter is getting called so many times here?

--------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-deluan-maven</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/deluan/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

It seems that the authorization method is being called when the `shiro:hasAnyRoles` is called. Above is how I added the Deluan repository in my pom.xml for being able to use the shiro tags inside the jsf pages I have. One of the sample jsf page I have is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
      xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:shiro="http://shiro.apache.org/tags">

<h:head>
    <title>Welcome Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <shiro:hasAnyRoles name="admin,backup-admin,sys-admin">
        <h2>     Welcome!        </h2>
    </shiro:hasAnyRoles>
    <shiro:hasAnyRoles name="user,admin">
        <h2>     You too Welcome!        </h2>
    </shiro:hasAnyRoles>   

</h:body>
</html>
```

This simple page is used as the welcome page and every time its refreshed it calls the doAuthentication method 3 times it seems. Surely I have done something wrong here :( Any pointers where should I look?

=========================== Edited ============================

```
<!--  Shiro Environment Listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You should add your configuration and any other specifics about your application.

Comment: I apologize for less info in the question. I added bunch of info now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason I had this problem was I didn't configure the `cacheManager` in `securityManager`. Shiro didn't know the Authorization info of your account, cause there is no caching.

Add a `cacheManager`, the code below using memory cache manager, you can add others like `ehcache`, here is a sample using memory cache:

```
@Bean
protected CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager();
}
```

then add into `securityManager` : `securityManager.setCacheManager(cacheManager);`

Comment: Wow, I will give it a try and let you know the results, makes sense already :) Thanks.

Comment: Yes today I finally tried it, it does solve the problem indeed, just by adding a simple cache. Beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Oh God! I have been making a stupid mistake all along. I had included the repository from Deluan for JSF separately for configuring the taglibs for jsf following some old examples, did not realize that it is already included in the latest version of Shiro and hence the authorization methods were getting called multiple times. When I remove it from the dependency everything works very nice. @Brian Demers, thank you sir for your time and help :)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

----------------------------------------------------------------Edit------------------------------------------------------------

This does not really solve the problem, the errors go because shiro: tags itself stops working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are ignoring an error from `commonAuth.doGetAuthorizationInfo` which would result in an authenticated user being able to access your system.

What does `commonAuth.doGetAuthorizationInfo()` actually do?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have exception catchers everywhere. It is actually fetching the correct role and permission from the database and assigning(inside the commonAuth.doGetAuthorizationInfo) . I think I found the reason, inside my xhtml page i am calling multiple times the shiro:hasPermission, shiro:hasAnyRoles[jsp shiro tags](https://shiro.apache.org/jsp-tag-library.html). Did not think before that everytime they ought to call doAuthorizationInfo method. Is my suspicion right? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your subject might not be attached to the request correctly?  The realm should only be called once when the session starts (or if stateless once per request)

Comment: Ok this makes sense, the way I am doing it is as follows, String code = oar.getCode();
            GoogleToken token = new GoogleToken(code); Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject(); if(!currentUser.isAuthenticated()){
                    currentUser.login(token);
                    ThreadContext.bind(currentUser);
                }

Comment: Do you see an issue here? Once the user authenticates and I receive a code I apply for the access token and the token is used to login the subject. GoogleToken is just a authentication token which i prepared following this tutorial from shiro, [sample facebook app](https://mrdwnotes.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-apache-shiro-security-to-allow-login-via-facebook-part-1/)

Comment: I added more config information about how I set up my xhtml code with the shiro: jsp tags from DeLuans repository, isn't that how I should do this? @Brian Demers

Comment: You _shouldn't_ need to call `.login`directly. If the Shiro servlet filter is setup correctly this code will execute automatically (meaning you don't need to deal with any of the subject/request state)

Comment: Ok I will play with it and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: if i do not manually login the user by doing subject.login(token) then the user does not really get logged in it seems.  I edited the question and added the shiro filter config. Please let me know if you see a issue.